# Please help identify a step-up DC-DC converter IC

Tags: integrated-circuit, dc-dc-converter, code

Thank you for the opportunity to share this with the community.
I'm in the process of repairing the PCB inside the SkyWatcher.
So far I have identified the blown chip as a dc-DC boost converter integrated circuit (IC). The IC is responsible for boosting two AA batteries to 3.3v needed by the CPU and the rest of the circuit. Unfortunately, from the markings which I have managed to recover (6sF and P714), I can't pin it to any manufacturer or the IC model number.
I would really appreciate your help. If anyone could recognize the markings or have an idea where to direct my search, I would really appreciate it. Please see the pictures attached.
Thank you heaps!

[image: Fig.1 DC-DC upconverter]

[image: Fig.2 DC-DC upconverter]

[image: Fig.3 Controller PCB]

[image: Fig.4 Schematics]

Comment: Can you buzz out a schematic for what's connected to what?

Comment: Diodes Inc. Possibly AP6714?

Comment: Thank you, Tim Williams, you are correct!! Please post the official answer.
Looking at the datasheet of AP6714 it indeed matches the schematics on the board. I could find the answer by searching google high and low for several days. I also appreciate the effort of everyone who looked at the question and spend their time pondering the answer (Hearth and other..)

Comment: @TimWilliams Indeed, it is! How did you find it?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Diodes Inc. Possibly AP6714?

The Diodes logo is visible (the sort of "D|:" marking).  The rest on that line is probably date code or lot, nothing relevant.

The application is clearly some manner of switching regulator; there are capacitors at the input and output, and an inductor; it appears to be synchronous type as there's no diode (but a back side photo would confirm this).  Curiously, it seems to have an outboard current sense resistor.

The package is MSOP-10 or thereabouts.

Going on Digi-Key can be a long shot, depending on age of the part.  Turns out there's only a dozen matches of that description, of which AP6714 is still reasonably current, and seems to have a matching pinout.